# Use existed strings or add new into transifex for filters titles on the user history page in mod tools

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/history/:userId

1. > [image]

   String: `User has been banned from review`.
2. > [image]

   String: `User accessed site`.
3. > [image]

   String: `User suspended`. There is similar string in transifex (`a9a411b9cd46206591d9355bb21be589`), but it isn't used here.
4. > [image]

   Strings:

   1. `User attended an event and met a Stack Overflow employee`
   2. `user attended an event and met an stack overflow employee`
5. etc.

I've found similar strings in the transifex: `278ca9cd43754e74193307e27b6ce278` and `d97bef9a6f8b3e3b825e80877173f152`, but looks like they aren't used. Could you use existed strings or add new, so we will be able to translate it?